# @lru_cache decorator excessive cache misses

Tags: python, function, caching, memoization, functools

How can you configure `lru_cache` to key its cache based on actual values received, rather than how the function was called?

```
>>> from functools import lru_cache
>>> @lru_cache
... def f(x=2):
...     print("reticulating splines...")
...     return x ** 2
...
>>> f()
reticulating splines...
4
>>> f(2)
reticulating splines...
4
>>> f(x=2)
reticulating splines...
4
```

In other words, only the first call above should be a cache miss, the other two should be cache hits.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=lru_cache#functools.lru_cache) do state: _Distinct argument patterns may be considered to be distinct calls with separate cache entries. For example, f(a=1, b=2) and f(b=2, a=1) differ in their keyword argument order and may have two separate cache entries_. Looks like you can use the `f.cache_info()` method to see the actual cache hits/misses.

Comment: I'm aware, but I don't think it's a sensible default behavior - the calls are for all practical purposes the same. I'd like to wrap (or replace) lru_cache in such a way that avoids the cache misses for all the various different spellings of the same underlying call.

Comment: Looks like the [`make_key` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py#L448) is responsible for hashing the argument pattern. You could patch that at some point to enforce that those patterns are the same.

Comment: @bnaecker: Nope, because the behavior the question is trying to achieve depends on the function signature, which `make_key` doesn't know.

Comment: Why are `f()` and `f(x=2)` not treated the same? Isn't `args=()` and `kwds={'x': 2}` in both cases?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica True, it may not be enough to patch `_make_key`. The `_lru_cache_wrapper` function which _uses_ that might be patchable, since that has access to the function at that point. Without trying it, I really don't know. But it seems possible.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Nope. Default values are not keyword arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do that, you would have to go through the process of binding arguments to formal parameters. The *actual* process of doing that is implemented in C code with no public interface, but there's a (much slower) reimplementation in [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object). This is about 100x slower than using `functools.lru_cache` normally:

```
import functools
import inspect

def mycache(f=None, /, **kwargs):
    def inner(f):
        sig = inspect.signature(f)
        f = functools.lru_cache(**kwargs)(f)
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            bound.apply_defaults()
            return f(*bound.args, **bound.kwargs)
        return wrapper
    if f:
        return inner(f)
    return inner

@mycache
def f(x):
    print("reticulating splines...")
    return x ** 2
```

If the performance penalty of that approach is too much, you can instead use the following trick, which requires more code duplication but runs much faster, only about 2x slower than using `lru_cache` normally (and sometimes faster, with keyword arguments):

```
@functools.lru_cache
def _f(x):
    print("reticulating splines...")
    return x ** 2

def f(x=2):
    return _f(x)
```

This uses the much faster C-level argument binding to normalize the call to the memoized helper function, but requires duplicating the function's parameters 3 times: once in the outer function's signature, once in the helper's signature, and once in the call to the helper.

Comment: Works great.  How's your C? Any interest to put together a CPython PR adding "normalize" argument into `lru_cache` directly?